# Как найти open source проект под себя

Tags: java-ee, java, opensource

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста, найти не большой и не слишком сложный open source проект на java. Я хочу получить опыт, перед тем как устраиватся на джуниора, и считаю, что open source лучшее решение. Но, к сожалению, никак не могу найти проект, который мне бы подошел. Желательно, чтобы там был спринг и мавен. Извините за столь глупый вопрос)

Comment: плохая идея тчк

Comment: @Not even close, я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите влиться в опенсорсный проект и потом представлять ваш вклад на собеседованиях?

Comment: @Etki, да, все правильно) Да и просто опыт получить.

Comment: @Not even close, за подобными вопросами сюда вряд ли стоит обращаться. Не ожидайте, что вам поднесут все "на блюдечке". Все далеко не так просто, как вы полагаете. Ищите сами, раскапывайте, вливайтесь.

Comment: @Not even close, я бы писал что-то свое, небольшое, но где можно сделать всё ясно, доступно, красиво и не пришлось бы показывать, где ваш код, а где не ваш. Но это только мое мнение.

В принципе, есть вот такой вот проект, где писать *с кем-то* скорее всего не придется, но при выполнении минимальных требований проекта можно без проблем управиться за неделю: http://blogmvc.com/

Ну и вообще можно особо не париться, а кидать пулреквесты там и сям по мелким (или немелким и детальным) доработкам. Здесь действительно вряд ли за вас найдут конкретный проект, но вы **наверняка** ->

Comment: видите именно то, что ищете, по два-пять раз на дню.

upd: ну и да, сунуться даже в минимальный, но популярный OSS - это огромный гемор с поддержкой и десятикратное переписывание одних и тех же мест. Я бы не стал рассматривать это как вариант, если предполагается некоторый результат в какие-то сроки, который впоследствие не будет дорабатываться.

Comment: @0xFFh, а куда ему еще обращаться?

Видимо, ХэшКод уже стал достаточно популярным и авторитетным, раз люди сюда идут с такими просьбами (вот только сможет ли кто-нибудь *реально* помочь...).

Answer (score 2):

Пробовали искать на GitHub? Что-нибудь вроде вот [этого](https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=java+spring+maven).

Comment: Только там и пробовал)

Answer (score 2):

Можете попробовать на [JavaTalks](http://javatalks.ru/topics/22420) стукнуться. Там пишут форум. Со спрингом и мавеном, как вы хотите )